# generate multi-dimentional array from PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to obtain the same result mith my mysql table. Below my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `map_point` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Location` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=898 ;
```

---

type are Phase1, Phase2...... The final multi-dimentional array must show like this:

```
$data = array ( "Phase1" => array("name"=>"Phase 1", "icon"=>"icons/iconb.png"),
                "Phase2" => array("name"=>"Phase 2", "icon"=>"icons/icong.png"),
                "Phase3" => array("name"=>"Phase 3", "icon"=>"icons/iconr.png"),
                "Phase2p" => array("name"=>"Phase 2+", "icon"=>"icons/icony.png"),
                "Phase3p" => array("name"=>"Phase 3+", "icon"=>"icons/iconpi.png"),
                "RollOut2012" => array("name"=>"Roll Out 2012","icon"=>"icons/iconor.png"),
                "RollOut120sites" => array("name"=>"Roll Out 120 Sites", "icon"=>"icons/iconma.png"),                   
);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The matter is to demonstrate how to return an associative array grouped by the values of the specified column in the result set.

Comment: I've tried this:                                                $result0 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM `map_point`");
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type AS name, icon FROM `map_point`");                                                       while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    array_push($json_data1, $row1);
    }

Comment: Where do you get the keys "Phase 1", "Phase3p", "RollOut2012", etc... from?

Comment: there are already in my table. Colum "type".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something of the sort

```
$jsondata = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT type AS name, icon FROM map_point");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  if(!array_key_exists($row['type'], $jsondata))
    $jsondata[$row['name']] = $row
  else
    array_push($jsondata[$row['name']] , $row)
}
```

Comment: INPUT:                                                            <?php
    $jsondata = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT type AS name, icon FROM map_point");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    if(!array_key_exists($row['name'], $jsondata))
    $jsondata[$row1['name']] = $row;
    else
    array_push($jsondata1[$row1['name']] , $row);
    }
   var_dump($jsondata);                                             ?> for output i have the all raw for each type.

Comment: array
  'Phase1' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Phase1' (length=6)
      'icon' => string 'icons/iconb.png' (length=15)
      0 => 
        array
          'name' => string 'Phase1' (length=6)
          'icon' => string 'icons/iconb.png' (length=15)
      1 =>

Comment: The correct query is $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT type AS name, icon FROM map_point"); Thank you very mush for your help.... Its work fine now!!!!